# Почему foo.x = undefined?

Tags: javascript

Вроде как в коде ниже и всё должно быть просто, но тем не менее принцип работы не поддаётся моему пониманию.

При присваивании foo.x = foo = obj, как я понимаю, сначала выполняется правый участок кода, то есть в переменную "foo" заносится ссылка на объект {n:2} из переменной obj, и потом в свойство "foo.x" должна вроде как заноситься аналогичная ссылка, но выходит undefined. Может кто-то объяснить из-за чего подобное происходит?

```js
let foo = {};
let obj = {n:2};
        
foo.x = foo = obj;

console.log(foo.x);
console.log(foo);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Ну вы же сами написали, что в переменной `foo` теперь храниться ссылка на `obj`. Ссылка на объект, который был в `foo`, потерялась.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko но ведь, на момент присваивания foo.x переменная foo уже хранит ссылку на obj и почему это не присваивается foo.x?

Comment: Кажется я уже видел тут этот вопрос пару раз

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Другие участники пытаются донести мысль, что при выполнении строки `foo.x = foo = obj;` имена объектов сначала разыменовываются, как бы заменяются указателями на объекты.

Объектов два, давайте обозначим их A и B. Изначально `foo` указывает на A, `obj` на B. Тогда та строка превратится в такую последовательность действий:

1. Разыменование, которое превращает `foo.x = ...` в нечто вроде `A.x = ...` То, как это устроено, детально поясняет [ответ от Igor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/987656/198251).
2. Положить в переменную `foo` ту же ссылку, что в переменной `obj`. Теперь они обе указывают на B.
3. Положить в поле `x` объекта A ссылку из переменной `foo`. Спасибо разыменовыванию.

Вот небольшое изменение исходного кода, которое поможет лучше понять ситуацию:

```js
let foo = {};  // A
let old_foo = foo;  // сохраним A
let obj = {n:2};  // B
        
foo.x = foo = obj;
// foo указывает на B
// A.x = *foo = B

console.log(foo.x);  // B.x = undefined
console.log(foo);  // B
console.log(obj);  // B
console.log(old_foo);  // сохранённное A
```

Как показывает вывод, объект А никуда не делся, просто раньше на него была потеряна ссылка, а присвоение поля `x` прошло корректно, хоть и не на тот объект, который кажется очевидным.

Comment: Спасибо) После вашего объяснения вроде как образовалось понимание того как всё устроено.

Answer (score 4):

```js
let holder = { _foo: {} };
Object.defineProperty(holder, 'foo', {
  get() { 
    return this._foo; 
  },
  set(value) 
  {
    console.log("set foo", value);
    this._foo = value;
  }
});
Object.defineProperty(holder.foo, 'x', {
  get() { 
    return this._x; 
  },
  set(value) 
  {
    console.log("set foo.x", value);
    this._x = value;
  }
});
holder.foo.x = holder.foo = {n:2};
console.log(holder);
console.log(holder.foo);
```

Дело в том, что объекты в JS содержат не поля, а свойства.

Представьте, что нет свойств, а есть только гетеры и сетеры:

```
holder.getFoo().setX((holder.setFoo({ n: 2 }), holder.getFoo()));
```

Функция `setX` вызовется, хотя метода `setX` у результа вызова `holder.getFoo` в этот момент уже не будет.

Comment: Понимания конечно у меня пока ещё не появилось, но в любом случае спасибо) через пару часов зайду, попытаюсь повторно в это вникнуть

Answer (score 0):

Потому что `foo.x` изначально **undefined**, а раз выскочил **undefined**, то js его сразу вернет и продолжит выполнение следующих команд. Так что нужно что-то запихнуть в свойство `foo.x`.

Например вот так

```js
let foo = {};
let obj = {
  n: 2
};

foo.x = obj.n;

console.log(foo.x);
console.log(foo);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: `foo.x изначально undefined, а раз выскочил undefined, то js его сразу вернет и продолжит выполнение следующих команд` – неверно. Посмотрите мой ответ, присвоение происходит успешно, просто не в тот объект, который ожидалось.